# Get namespace of call context

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a very simple question, but the answer might be rather complicated.
"How can I get the namespace of the block where a function call was made?"

So, when I do:

```
1. <?php
2. namespace TestTest;
3.
4. $myobj->doMethod();
```

How can $myobj->doMethod() know that the namespace on line 4. is TestTest?

Comment: __NAMESPACE__ constant. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php  What's the problem?

Comment: @IgorGreg `__NAMESPACE__` refers to the current namespace. Unless he passes that as an argument, it's no good here. (I'm assuming that's not an option)

Comment: @rjdown It is indeed no option.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if the method is not called from the global scope. That's because there's no real way to backtrace it (please someone correct me here if that's not the case!). Simplest solution is to put your call in a function. It's likely you'll be using a method anyway if you're doing this sort of thing. If that's the case then you can use a combination of the debug_backtrace function and the reflection class:

file1.php:

```
<?php

namespace myns;

require 'file2.php';

function example($class) {
    echo $class->nstest();
}

$class = new \myotherns\someclass();
echo example($class);
```

file2.php:

```
<?php

namespace myotherns;

class someclass {

    function nstest() {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
        $caller = end($backtrace);
        $reflection = new \ReflectionFunction($caller['function']);
        return $reflection->getNamespaceName();
    }

}
```

Or all in one file:

```
<?php
namespace myns {
    $someclass = new \myotherns\someclass();
    echo example($someclass);
    function example($class) {
        echo $class->nstest();
    }
}

namespace myotherns {
    class someclass {
        function nstest() {
            $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
            $caller = end($backtrace);
            $reflection = new \ReflectionFunction($caller['function']);
            return $reflection->getNamespaceName();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an [online demo](https://3v4l.org/hIMRZ)

You'll need to tweak it depending on how you end up calling your method, but it should be simple enough.

Comment: I've seen this earlier, but it's not what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you are out of options :( Reflection is the only way to do it without passing it as an argument.